# Abreviação de texto <td> não funciona

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de aplicar abreviação em um `<td>`:

```
<td> TextoTextoTextoTextoTextoTexto </td>
```

Exibindo apenas:

```
TextoTexto...
```

Tentei usar `style="text-overflow:ellipsis"` mas não funcionou.

*Detalhe: preciso que seja **inline**, pois já tenho folha de estilo, não posso alterar e nem colocar estilo separado.*

Comment: Downvoter, o que não entendeu na pergunta, que eu possa estar melhorando para você?

Comment: O downvote não é meu, mas o de fechamento é :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Mas essa pergunta eles não usaram inline  Ou eu que não estou entendendo mais nada! hahaha

Comment: `style=""` é o mesmo comportamento de colocar em um seletor, as propriedades não mudam a escrita e nem nada, basta copiar de dentro do seletor da outra resposta e colocar dentro do `style=""`.

Comment: @rbz eu sou o downvoter. Tirei o voto agora que você editou. Estava confusa e levando os usuários a responder algo que não condizia com sua necessidade

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Concordo! É que as vezes é algo tão simples que se torna difícil fazer a pergunta!

Comment: Pessoal, acho que esse `td` não aceita fazer isso. Eu coloquei uma `div` para por o texto dentro e funcionou. Seria somente essa a forma mesmo, será!?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Nunca tinha parado pra pensar tão simples. Vergonha! 

Comment: @rbz tranquilo, estamos todos aqui para aprender e compartilhar ;)

Comment: @rbz funcionou colocar dentro de TD? Me informa isso, se não funcionar vou reabrir a pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não... Até pelo que pesquisei, não funciona direto no `td`, tem que colocar o texto numa `div`. Aí já altera a pergunta novamente, e pra "piorar", tem que setar o `width` fixo, aí o bendito não ajusta com o tamanho da `td`, aí eu percebi que estou perdendo tempo por "perfumaria" que não precisava agora. Então posteriormente iria abrir outra pergunta sobre ajuste de tamanho da `div`com `td` truncando texto... 

Comment: Não precisa fixar o width, basta usar `100%` no div, votei para reabrir a pergunta dup não cobre em nada o problema, então assim que reabrir transformo em resposta

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento aí ele assume 100% e não trunca nada! Mesmo que tenho `width` no `th`, no `td`, na `div`...

Comment: @rbz é porque no table tem que aplicar `table-layout: fixed`, veja o comentário que fiz na resposta do Wallace, tem um exemplo de uso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar `overflow:ellipsis;` e `white-space:nowrap;` com o seletor `td {}` ou no elemento `<td style="">` não vai funcionar porque os TDs e THs se comportam diferente de elementos do tipo `block` e `inline-block`, ou seja eles teriam que ter suas larguras fixadas para que funcionasse, caso contrário a tabela irá expandir para além do tamanho fixado em table, por exemplo:

```css
.foo {
  width: 400px;
}
.foo thead {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.foo td, .foo th {
    border: 1px #e0e0e0 solid;
}

.text-limit {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table class="foo">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>head1</th>
            <th>head2</th>
            <th>head3</th>
            <th>head4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-limit">foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz</td>
            <td>cell2_1</td>
            <td>cell3_1</td>
            <td>cell4_1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell1_1</td>
            <td>cell2_1</td>
            <td>cell3_1</td>
            <td>cell4_1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note que mesmo fixando o tamanho pra 400px na tabel no momento que usar um TD ou TD com o layout expandiu, para resolver isto basta usar a propriedade `table-layout: fixed;`:

```css
.foo {
  width: 400px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.foo thead {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.foo td, .foo th {
    border: 1px #e0e0e0 solid;
}

.text-limit {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table class="foo">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>head1</th>
            <th>head2</th>
            <th>head3</th>
            <th>head4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-limit">foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz</td>
            <td>cell2_1</td>
            <td>cell3_1</td>
            <td>cell4_1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell1_1</td>
            <td>cell2_1</td>
            <td>cell3_1</td>
            <td>cell4_1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note que a tabela pode usar 100% também e o efeito ainda funciona:

```css
.foo {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.foo thead {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.foo td, .foo th {
    border: 1px #e0e0e0 solid;
}

.text-limit {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table class="foo">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>head1</th>
            <th>head2</th>
            <th>head3</th>
            <th>head4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-limit">foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz</td>
            <td>cell2_1</td>
            <td>cell3_1</td>
            <td>cell4_1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell1_1</td>
            <td>cell2_1</td>
            <td>cell3_1</td>
            <td>cell4_1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

### Usando de forma inline

Basta copiar o exemplo do `.text-limit` para o elemento TD desejado, assim:

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed;">

...

<tr>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;">foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz</td>
    <td>cell2_1</td>
    <td>cell3_1</td>
    <td>cell4_1</td>
</tr>

...
```

No entanto se quer aplicar a todos elementos e você tem controle sobre o HTML você poderia simplesmente adicionar um elemento style assim:

```
<style>
.minhatabela {
  width: 100%;
}

.minhatabela th, .minhatabela td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

E no HTML apenas adicionar isto:

```
<table class="minhatabela">
```

Ou se acredita que o seu CSS futuramente será customizado de diferentes formas e pretende com isto aproveitar em vários elementos e páginas o ideal seria criar o seu proprio `.css` a parte, fora dos frameworks (como materialize), por exemplo, cria um arquivo chamado:

```
/projeto/css/main.css
```

E dentro dele coloque todas customizações que pretende, incluindo o das tabelas e linka no HTML assim:

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

É possível sim, talvez ele não esteja funcionando sozinho, mas acompanhado das propriedades `white-space`, `overflow` e um `width` definido no container, funciona...

```html
<h2>text-overflow: ellipsis:</h2>
<div class="b" style="

  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;

">Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: Felipe, agradeço a força! Mas eu gostaria inline, pois já tenho folha de estilo, mas nesse caso queria direto na linha. 

Comment: @rbz mas sempre é necessário ter o `white-space:nowrap`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Mas esse `white-space:nowrap` pode ser inline? Porque se puder, posso usar: `<td style:"white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;">`?

Comment: @rbz, está inline... https://www.codecademy.com/articles/html-inline-styles, a diferença é que eu pulei algumas linhas, você não precisa fazer isso

Comment: @FelipeDuarte Eu que escrevi errado, o seu não funcionou! Usei sem a borda: `style="text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;width:50px;overflow:hidden"` não funciona

Comment: Será que é por causa que é um `td`?

Comment: Coloque seu código na pergunta e se possível os css´s que afetam o elemento, pode não estar funcionando por vários fatores, comportamento e tipo do container, estilos sendo sobrepostos...

Comment: O CSS é um Framework: [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente, eu deixo uma classe pré-definida para fazer isso. Acho que a é a melhor forma de se trabalhar no CSS

```css
.text-limit{
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   overflow: hidden;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="text-limit" style="width:50px">
   Meu nome é Wallace
</div>

<div class="text-limit" style="width:75px">
   Meu nome é Wallace
</div>


<div class="text-limit" style="width:100px">
   Meu nome é Wallace
</div>

<div class="text-limit" style="width:130px">
   Meu nome é Wallace
</div>
```

Por padrão, eu sempre combino `overflow: hidden`, `text-overflow: ellipsis` e `white-space: nowrap`.

Comment: Eu preciso que seja inline professor! Tipo isso: `<td style:"white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;">` ... Sei que a melhor forma é no CSS ou num estilo, mas nesse caso preciso que seja direto na linha.

Comment: Tá, mas qual é a dificuldade?

Comment: WallaceMaxters o comportamento de `<TD>` é diferente de `DIV`, ou seja não tem como aplicar diretamente no TD ou TH, teria que usar um elemento dentro do TD, por exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/3t7kaxy8/ (cc @rbz)

Comment: Eu sei, mas a resposta foi dada antes, né. Eu estou meio ocupado agora, depois vejo se dá tempo de eu alterar (talvez eu exclua)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters só estava dando um caminho para uma futura edição :( com um exemplo, eu ia editar a sua resposta, mas fiquei com receio de como a comunidade iria olhar isso (tentativa de resposta)

Comment: Ah, se puder editar, tá de boa, kkkkk. Eu esto meio agarrado hoje.